# Fill color based on values from other data set in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, expression, ssrs-2014, ssrs-2017

I'm trying to fill colors based on table records.

From SQL Server AdventureWorks2017 database:

```
          select * from [HumanResources].[Department]
```

I have two dataset:

```
           1st : select * from [HumanResources].[Department]

            DepartmentID                         Name                            GroupName                                          Status
            ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            1                                Engineering                    Research and Development                       Cancelled
            2                                Tool Design                    Research and Development                       Blacklist
            3                                Sales                          Sales and Marketing                            Approved
            4                                Marketing                      Sales and Marketing                            All good
            5                                Purchasing                     Inventory Management                           xxx
            6                                Research and Development       Research and Development                       yyy
            7                                Production                     Manufacturing                                  zzz
            8                                Production                     Control Manufacturing                          xxx
            9                                Human Resources                Executive General and Administration           zzz
            10                               Finance                        Executive General and Administration           aaa
            11                               Information Services           Executive General and Administration           xxx
            12                               Document Control               Quality Assurance                              yyy
            13                               Quality Assurance              Quality Assurance                              zzz
            14                               Facilities and Maintenance     Executive General and Administration           aaa
            15                               Shipping and Receiving         Inventory Management                           bbb
            16                               Executive                      Executive General and Administration           aaa
```

**the 2nd**, I have a requirement to get the data like below and display in the SSRS report:

```
                Name0                                Name1                                      Name2                           Name3                                      Name4
            -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            Document Control           Facilities and Maintenance                Information Services           Production Control                  Research and Development
             Engineering                Finance                                     Marketing                      Purchasing                       Sales
             Executive                 Human Resources                             Production                   Quality Assurance                   Shipping and Receiving
              NULL                     NULL                                         NULL                         NULL                               Tool Design
```

The above data I'm getting using below query:

```
            WITH Table1 AS
            (
                SELECT  [Name]
                FROM    [HumanResources].[Department]
            ), CTE AS
            (
                SELECT  [Name], COL, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Col ORDER BY [Name]) AS Row
                FROM    (   SELECT [Name],
                                    5 - NTILE(5) OVER(ORDER BY [Name] DESC) AS Col
                            FROM Table1  
                        ) c
            )
            SELECT [0], [1], [2], [3], [4]
            FROM CTE 
            PIVOT (MAX([Name]) FOR Col IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4])) AS Pvt
            ORDER BY Row;
```

Also, in addition to the above requirement, another requirement is to fill the colors in the **2nd result set** based on "GroupName" and "Status" which is "another dataset" values; 
which I'm getting using :

```
       select * from [HumanResources].[Department]
```

I'm trying below expressions, to fill the colors for the 2nd data set:

```
      =IIF(LOOKUP((Fields!ID0.Value or Fields!ID1.Value or Fields!ID2.Value or Fields!ID3.Value or Fields!ID4.Value),Fields!Name.Value,Fields!GroupName.Value="Research and Development","DsetAll"),"GREEN","WHITE") 

      =IIF(LOOKUP((Fields!ID0.Value or Fields!ID1.Value or Fields!ID2.Value or Fields!ID3.Value or Fields!ID4.Value),Fields!Name.Value,Fields!GroupName.Value,"DsetAll")="Research and Development","GREEN","WHITE")
```

The problem is NON of the above expressions working fine.

**EDIT:**
The below expression looks working good:

```
 =IIF(LOOKUP(Fields!ID0.Value ,Fields!Name.Value,Fields!GroupName.Value,"DsetAll")="Research and Development","BLUE","RED")
```

It looks like, "OR" inside a "lookup" is not working. How can I make this work? Any other ways?

In the **2nd result set**, The idea is to make:

```
        if groupname "Research and Development" and status is "Cancelled" then "Green"
       if groupname "Research and Development" and status is "Blacklist" then "Green"
       if groupname "Sales and Marketing" and status is "Approved" then "Green"
                if status is "All good" then Gray
                if groupname "Manufacturing" then Blue
                if groupname "Control   Manufacturing" then red
                if groupname "Executive General and Administration" then pink
                if groupname "Quality Assurance" then Violet
                Else its should be white
```

The 1st expression is not showing any filled color.
Additionally, the NULL/Blank should not have any color.

and the 2nd expression has error:

```
            The Error occurred during local report processing.
            The definition of the report '/ColorTest' is invalid.
            The BackgroundColor expression for the text box 'ID0' contains an error: [BC30201] Expression expected.
```

How can I achieve this? Or, please let me know if there are any other ways to achieve same thing? Thanks

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't join to the dataset using the group name for color and then use that rather than lookupset? If colors are static.. why not use a case statement to hard code it in your dataset query? I always use lookup as a last resort.. if and only if I cannot join to the data I need

Comment: Sorry I didn’t get it clearly. Could you please provide bit details? The group name, I don’t want to display in the report. This group name is for setting the background cell colour.Moreover, the Colors are static, however the number of records are dynamic. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the result of your pivot query so we can see what the possible relation between the result and the select * from [HumanResources].[Department] is?

Comment: The results of the Pivot query is in the question. The table above the Pivot query (Name0, Name1... Name4 columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing that you have Name0 through to Name4 as static columns.. you could simply join each column back to the resource table to get the status and based on the result.. return a color and then use that color for the cell in the report.

I would approach this by first wrapping your Pivot with a cte and get a tidy output..

Something like

```
    , my_pivot_result as (

     SELECT [0], [1], [2], [3], [4]
                FROM CTE 
                PIVOT (MAX([Name]) FOR Col IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4])) AS Pvt

    )
,my_status as (

select my_pivot_result .* 
, isnull(col1_name.status,'') as col1_status
, isnull(col1_name.groupname,'') as col1_groupname
, isnull(col2_name.status,'') as col2_status
, isnull(col2_name.groupname,'') as col2_groupname
, isnull(col3_name.status,'') as col3_status
, isnull(col3_name.groupname,'') as col3_groupname
, isnull(col4_name.status,'') as col_status
, isnull(col4_name.groupname,'') as col4_groupname

from my_pivot_result 

left join [HumanResources].[Department] col1_name
 on col1_name.name = my_pivot_result.name0

left join [HumanResources].[Department] col2_name
 on col2_name.name = my_pivot_result.name1

left join [HumanResources].[Department] col3_name
 on col3_name.name = my_pivot_result.name2

left join [HumanResources].[Department] col4_name
 on col4_name.name = my_pivot_result.name3
)

Select * from my_status
```

now for each row, you should have a status and the groupname.. Now use a case statement to build another column for color..

something like..

```
    case when  col1_groupname = 'Research and Development'
       and col1_status in('Blacklist', 'Cancelled') then 'Green'

 else 'white' end as col1_color

    .
    .
    .
```

Keeping building the case statement until you have all the combinations

now in the front end, use an expression for each cell to display the color and use the color field value..

Answer (score 0):

This way the expression should work, but I would recommend using another approach (maybe using a calculated field to store specific information in one field instead of five separate ID fields):

```
=IIF(LOOKUP(Fields!ID0.Value, Fields!Name.Value, Fields!GroupName.Value, "DsetAll") = "Research and Development" Or
     LOOKUP(Fields!ID1.Value, Fields!Name.Value, Fields!GroupName.Value, "DsetAll") = "Research and Development" Or
     LOOKUP(Fields!ID2.Value, Fields!Name.Value, Fields!GroupName.Value, "DsetAll") = "Research and Development" Or
     LOOKUP(Fields!ID3.Value, Fields!Name.Value, Fields!GroupName.Value, "DsetAll") = "Research and Development" Or
     LOOKUP(Fields!ID4.Value, Fields!Name.Value, Fields!GroupName.Value, "DsetAll") = "Research and Development" 
    ,"BLUE"
    ,"RED")
```