# Switch cell fill color in SSRS report

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm teaching myself SSRS, and I've built a report that I would like to use.  Each product has it's own page, with a table of specifications.

The cell fill colors of the report will vary depending on the category of product (white grapes, red grapes, black grapes.)

Rather than create a seperate report for each category, I would like to change the fill colors depending on the category.  Below is my code, but it's generating an error.  I based this on another answer in stack overflow ([Fill color based on values from other data set in SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56721988/fill-color-based-on-values-from-other-data-set-in-ssrs))

```
=switch(
    (
        Fields!new_type.Value.Equals("White")
    ),  #749b53
    ,(
        Fields!new_type.Value.Equals("Red")
    ), #9D2347
    ,(
        Fields!new_type.Value.Equals("Black")
        #3D234f
    )
```

This is the error I'm getting:
"The BackgroundColor expression for the text box 'new_arraname' contains an error: [BC31085] Date constant is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, you are missing a comma and bracket.

```
=switch(
    Fields!new_type.Value="White","#749b53",
    Fields!new_type.Value="Red","#9D2347",
    Fields!new_type.Value="Black","#3D234f"
    )
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still with an error:  The BackgroundColor expression for the text box 'Textbox54' contains an error: [BC31085] Date constant is not valid

Comment: updated answer, SSRS is  trying to interpret #749b53 as a date literal instead use "#749b53"

Comment: Hi.  I'm not sure I understand, I already had it in quotations.  I can't see a difference from the code above.

Comment: Ok, so the problem is the HTML codes, when I switch it to "red", "green" and "black" it works - but I need the specific HTML code.  Any idea how the formatting of that should be?

Comment: `( Fields!new_type.Value.Equals("White")), #749b53` This was your original expression part, if you see here  you do not have "#749b53". Did you tried with double quotes. It shall work.

Comment: Double quotes isn't working.  Single quotes isn't working.  The both generate the same error.  Without quotes doesn't work either. :(  

```
switch(
    Fields!new_type.Value="White", ""#749b53"",
    Fields!new_type.Value="Red", "maroon",
    Fields!new_type.Value="Black", "black"
    )
```

Comment: Ok, my apologies.  Something else must have been off, because now this is working: 

 Fields!new_type.Value="White", "#749b53",

Comment: @Unicorn_tech could you please also upvote, it will help as well.